# I want to plot 2 variables in a pie chart in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot 2 variables in a single bar chart, so the chart looks like this:

[image: chart]

I tried this code, taken from another post, but it gave a weird graph:

```
data1 = df_master['doggo']
data2 = df_master['floofer']

# create a figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

plt.figure(0)
ax1.pie(data1)

plt.figure(1)
ax2.pie(data2)

plt.show();
```

[image: second chart]

The dataframe has these contents:

```
tweet_id                         2321 non-null object
in_reply_to_status_id_x          68 non-null float64
in_reply_to_user_id_x            68 non-null float64
timestamp                        2321 non-null object
text                             2321 non-null object
expanded_urls                    2271 non-null object
name                             1601 non-null object
doggo                            2321 non-null int64
floofer                          2321 non-null int64
pupper                           2321 non-null int64
puppo                            2321 non-null int64
rating                           2321 non-null float64
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Show the content of your `df_master` dataframe please.

Comment: @Diziet Asahi I showed the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include a sample of your dataframe. Please do the next time. I generated a random df looking like this:

```
   pupper  floofer  doggo  puppo
0       3        3      4      5
1       6        2      3      7
2       4        8      6      0
3       2        5      5      6
4       7        4      5      3
```

I then put the data into the "[long](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)" format with `melt`.

```
# put the data into the long format
df = df.melt(var_name='source')
```

Now it has many more rows, but only two columns. The source and the value.

```
   source  value
0  pupper      3
1  pupper      6
2  pupper      4
3  pupper      2
4  pupper      7
395  puppo      5
396  puppo      6
397  puppo      4
398  puppo      2
399  puppo      9
```

I then took a sum of the values for each source and passed that to `plt.pie`

```
plt.pie(df.groupby('source')['value'].sum())
```

I will leave the rest to you. Read up on [pie charts](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) and feel free to play around with *explode*, *colors*, *shadow* etc.